# Filtering a Source Component in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

We currently have a requirement to pull in financial transactions into a budget database for reporting. Currently, we grab ALL financial records (slow query) and then we grab ALL budgets. We then do a merge join to filter down the financial records to only those that we have budgets on. The ideal way to do this would be to first pull all budgets, feed that into another component that will then generate a query that pulls only those transactions that are needed.

Example:

`TableA` in `DatabaseA` has an identity column called `FakeId`.

`TableB` in `DatabaseB` has the same identity column; however, `TableB` does not have a one-to-one mapping to `TableA`. Instead, the "mapping" (if it existed) would be one-to-zero or one. We want to grab ALL the financial records from `TableA` in `DatabaseA` where `FakeId` is in `TableB` in `DatabaseB`.

We cannot create Linked Servers between these two SQL servers, so doing a `SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE FakeId IN (SELECT FakeId FROM DatabaseB.TableB)` would not work.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Voted to move, this is better suited for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: What version of SQL Server-2005 or 2008+?

Comment: Sorry. I should have included that. 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, you can use two sources and join them using a merge join transformation.

Another (more data warehouse oriented) solution is to copy both tables to a separate database (often called a staging area) and then perform the logic on database level, using a variation on the query you proposed. This solution also allows you to implement indexes and other performance-enhancing techniques to optimize the integration.

Comment: That makes sense. Copying a full table is typically less intense than a complex query. Then we can optimize and do the appropriate joins. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use SSIS, I think you can use 'Lookup' component:

Implementing Lookup Logic in SQL Server Integration Services
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-lookup-logic-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for. The problem I ran into trying the above is that the Input brings back only 2 records (expected). When the Input is provided to the Lookup query, SQL returns 18 records, but the Lookup only returns 2 (not expected). I don't need the number of rows to match. The lookup needs to pull back ALL transactions where the input columns match (1 to many not 1 to 1).